# Using struct parameters in a function call in C

Tags: c

Problem with using the parameters from a struct in a function. I am new to C and I couldn't find any related solutions online. Please find the below code and help me how to use the parameters from a struct in a function.

```
typedef struct{
int rows;
int cols;
}matrix;

/* Find the number of rows and columns */
void computeRowsCols(matrix *str, int val)
{
    if (condition)
        {
        str.rows = 3;
        str.cols = 3;
        }
    else
        {
        str.rows = 6;
        str.cols = 6;
        }
}


/* Find the matrix with the number of rows and columns
void computeMatrix(int val)
{

    matrix str;
    computeRowsCols(&str,val);

    int A[str.rows][str.cols];
    int (*mat)[str.cols] = &A[str.cols]; /* Pointer to a matrix */

    if (condition)
        mat = func1(A);
    else
        mat = func2(A);

}
```

When I call **func1(A)**, I am manually entering the number of rows, cols. But I need to take the values of rows, cols from the function **computeRowsCols()** as commented below in the *required* section

```
int (*func1( int A[3][3]))[3] 
/* required : int (*func1( int A[str.rows][str.cols]))[str.cols] */
{
...
return A;
}

int (*func2( int A[6][6]))[6]
/* required : int (*func2( int A[str.rows][str.cols]))[str.cols] */
{
...
return A;
}

int main()
{
    int val = 10;
    computeMatrix(val);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The posted code shouldn't even compile.  The `if-else` in your `computeRowsCols()` function is badly broken.

Comment: And when passing a struct as pointer you'd use `->` rather than `.`.

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_pointers.htm

Comment: To me this is unclear. Are you asking how you can pass a variable size matrix to a function ?

Comment: @AndrewHenle This is just a sample code, the actual program is quite big and if you can help me with this part of the code, I would be thankful. `int (*func1( int A[3][3]))[3] 
/* required : int (*func1( int A[str.rows][str.cols]))[str.cols] */
{
...
return A;
}`

Comment: @4386427 Yes I need to pass a variable size matrix to a function. How can I do that?

Comment: The function could look: `void func(int rows, int cols, int A[][cols]) { ... };` and you'll call it like: `func(str.rows, str.cols, A);`

Comment: `void computeRowsCols(matrix *str, int val){ ...
        str.rows = 3;` does not compile and this post lacks the certain compiler error message.  Post all the compiler error messages and a [mcve]

Comment: @4386427 Thanks the problem is half solved. I am able to use rows and cols for `A[3][3]` as `A[rows][cols]` in `int (*func1( int rows, int cols, int A[][cols]))[3] 
/* required : int (*func1( int rows, int cols, int A[][cols]))[col]  */
{
...
return A;
}` But the only problem is it's not allowing me to use `cols` next to `int (*func1( int rows, int cols, int A[][cols]))` i.e i have to use `[3]` for the program to compile, but I need to insert `[col]` there.

Comment: @Cherry I don't understand what you are trying to do with this: `/* required : int (*func1( int rows, int cols, int A[][cols]))[col] */ { ... return A; }` It's illegal C code and consequently it's meaningless. My previous comment tells you how you declare the function and how you call. That's all. Just do it like the comment says and you're done :-)